# Word Document Saving very slowly

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007

I am proving support for a user who is using office 2007 on a windows XP machine.

When saving a word document, the application hangs for more than a minute or two before saving. Excel and powerpoint work fine. I have repaired the office installation but it is still very slow to save the document even just a space.

What can I do to salvage the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving it on another machine ?

If not and you save locally, since the problem is word-only a [normal.dot termination](http://www.pcdon.com/word-unstable-corrupted-normal-dot.html) should fix it.

Comment: Clarification questions should be asked in the comments section below the question itself, not in an answer. Also, when answering, avoid using short statements and links. You should explain the basic steps of your answer, when it solves the problem and reference the link. That way, in the event the link breaks your answer is still valid.